# meromorphic function with period one on the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $H$ be the upper half complex plane and $f$ be a meromorphic function on $H$. I wonder how to show that if $f$ satisfies $f(z+1)=f(z)$ for all $z\in H$, then $f$ can be written as 
$$f(z)=\tilde{f}(e^{2\pi i z}),$$

where $\tilde{f}$ is meromorphic in the unit disk with the origin removed.

I think here we are supposed to take something like 
$\tilde{f}=f\circ \log$ but I don't know how to prove it formally and use the condition $f(z+1)=f(z)$.

The original of this question is from Serre's a course in arithmetic, page 80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ q \to \frac{\log q}{2i \pi}$ is analytic $\Bbb{C}^* \to \Bbb{C/Z}$ (a Riemann surface) and it restricts to an analytic function $\{0 < |q| < 1\} \to \mathcal{H} / \Bbb{Z}$.

Thus if $f$ is meromorphic  on $\mathcal{H} / \Bbb{Z}$ (ie. meromorphic and $1$-periodic on $\mathcal{H}$) then $q \to f(\frac{\log q}{2i \pi})$ is meromorphic on $0 < |q| < 1$.

If $f$ has no pole for $\Im(z) > a$ then $f$ has a Laurent expansion $f(\frac{\log q}{2i \pi}) = \sum_n c_n q^n$ valid for $0 < |q| < e^{-2 \pi a}$ giving the Fourier series $f(z) = \sum_n c_n e^{2i \pi nz}$ for $\Im(z) > a$.

Comment: why is $q \to \frac{\log q}{2i \pi}$ analytic here? I remember the complex logarithm is analytic on $\mathbb C$ minus a ray but not analytic on a punctured disk...

Comment: Also, the composition of a meromorphic function with an analytic function is not necessarily meromorphic. You probably used some results like https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3153868/185631

Comment: If $u$ is analytic $A\to B$  and $v$ is meromorphic on $B$ then $v \circ u$ is meromorphic on $A$ (proof : locally $v = w/t$ with $w,t$ analytic and the composition of analytic functions is analytic). $\log$ is analytic $\Bbb{C^* \to C/2i\pi Z}$ the latter is a Riemann surface allowing to identify all the branches of the logarithm, and locally on $\Bbb{C}^*$ there is always one of them which is analytic.

Comment: anything still unclear ?